# Calculate grouped sum divided by total sum using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data:

```
Groups <- c("A","A", "B","B","B","A","B","A","A")
Values <- c(1,2,5,2,1,4,6,1,2)
DT <- data.table(Groups,Values)
```

I would like to calculate the sum of Values for each group and divide by the total sum of Values using data.table.  I could do it by creating an object prior to the data.table function like this:

```
total <- sum(DT$Values)
DT[,.(calc=sum(Values)/total), Groups]
```

But I'd like to know if there is a way to do this in just one data.table function.

Comment: I guess you know this, but there's also `DT[,.(calc=sum(Values)/sum(DT$Values)), Groups]`

Comment: or `DT[, {total = sum(Values); .SD[, sum(Values)/total, by = Groups]]` will avoid replicating the name of the `data.table`; if `..` makes it through to expressions, in the future this could work: `DT[, .SD[, sum(Values)/sum(..Values)], by = Groups]`